# Overriding module-level variables

Tags: python

From module A, is there a way to override a variable defined in the top level of module B ? Just so  that I want to run Module B's code with a temporary tweak of that variable, say in a unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just assign to the attribute *on* the module:

```
import moduleB

moduleB.some_variable = 'foo'
```

Note that any other code that already imported `some_variable` *as a global* is not going to be updated.

Comment: Also, if it's "for testing" as seems implied, if `some_variable` in `moduleB` affects the way the imported module is presented after `import`, then could get even more confusing. But if that's the case, this is the completely wrong track anyway ;)

Comment: @JonClements: I've done this; especially when you normally set a random value in the code, but for unit testing you need something stable.